# Have a good griddle-react plugin example?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, griddle

The plug-in documentation states:

> When adding functionality to Griddle, you’ll likely need to response to actions and update the application state. This can easily be done by adding action handling functions to your `reducer` object.

I am writing a plug-in to replace the default Pagination with bootstrap styled Pagination. This will need access to `getNext() getPrevious() and setPage()` in actions. I can clearly see how to access these from inside the Griddle package as the `local` plug-in does.

I am unsure how I would access these functions and state from a plug-in written in my application.

What do I need to import from Griddle? What do I need to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in addition to directly accessing the exported `selectors` and `actions`, both are available through React Context as well, e.g. in [`LocalPlugin.components.TableBodyContainer`](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/f57e594f230393717fed579fa97e89effb45242f/src/plugins/local/components/TableBodyContainer.js#L11-L19). Context *should* expose the "best" `selectors`/`actions` for the current `<Griddle />` after plugins have been applied.

Some work was started in https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/pull/743 to make selectors more composable, but the PR has gone stale.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. In the Story Book, the [**custom page size settings** story](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/caff6351694e5572bb1198a0fdfb6d617f0c1b05/stories/index.tsx#L1355-L1394) accesses the `selectors` and `actions` exports to give a plugin more direct access to the internals. The other stories around it do a fair job of demonstrating how to access Griddle internals from the a plugin.

Comment: Ok. I actually used that story to create an inline list display plugin.